# Using pfSense as a VPN client with two other routers

Tags: networking, router, vpn, pfsense

I'm trying to set up pfSense to sit inbetween my existing ISP router and another AP router I have. I had a setup originally where my second AP accessed the ISP router with the WAN port - this worked great as I could use the second AP as a VPN client.

What I'd like to do is use pfSense as a VPN client instead (for better OpenVPN acceleration), however when I connect a laptop to the second AP I'm unable to connect to the pfSense web console via the IP. I've produced a diagram of how it is setup, the main issue seems to be that I need to set the gateway for pfSense to a device on another subnet (this is how I did it with my second AP before). Unfortunately pfSense doesn't allow me to do that, so I assume I'm doing something wrong.... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

[Original and new setup diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y90m.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to set the gateway for pfSense to a device on another subnet"? PfSense's gateway should be 192.168.0.1, which is on a directly connected subnet. You also seem to be missing an IP address for pfSense. It needs two IP addresses. One for its WAN and one for its LAN.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I read some very old posts that there is an apparent 'bug' in pfSense where simply doing a fresh install with the correct settings helped. I didn't hold my breathe but low and behold it worked immediately after doing this.

In the end the setup I had is:
ISP Router on 192.168.0.1 (LAN to WAN on pfSense)
pfSense on 192.168.1.1 (WAN to ISP router, LAN to AP Router)
AP Router on 192.168.2.1 (WAN to LAN on pfSense)

I explicitly set no upstream gateway WAN when configuring the LAN.

Traffic now passes through perfectly! - now on to configuring OpenVPN :-)